# Spring Boot whitelabel error page / Error 404; does not find JSP files

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, war

Trying to use Spring Boot with MVC & JSP fails to show JSP pages at all, fails with a 404 error after the Controller has finished

So I'm trying to show a JSP page using Spring; I currently have the following code:

File structure

```
src/
  - main/java/ (java source root)
  - resources/static/ (static web root)
    - style.css (works fine)
  - webapp/
    - account/
      - view.jsp (the JSP file i'm trying to view)
```

`application.properties`

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

`AccountController.java`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/account")
public class AccountController {
    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accounts;

    @GetMapping("/view")
    public String viewAccount(Model model, @CookieValue("SESSION") String sessionId) {
        var account = accounts.findBySessionId(sessionId);
        model.addAttribute("loggedIn", account.isPresent());
        model.addAttribute("account", account.orElse(null));
        return "account/view";
    }
}
```

Now, when I access `localhost:8080/account/view`, then the mapping in the `AccountController` class is executed just fine.
My IDE (IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate) also knows that `return "account/view";` points to an existing file.
But in the web browser, I only ever land on a Whitelabel error page telling me about Error 404 / Not Found. I assume this is because something in the Spring Configuration is wrong, but I have no idea what that may be.

- I have already tried using a `WEB-INF` directory within the `webapp` directory (which i do not want), without success.
- I have tried adjusting the project file structure, configuration and dependencies to this working example project: https://github.com/jb-tester/springboot-war-jsp

When packaging the project using gradles `bootWar` task, then running that package, the result is even weirder;
When trying to access the endpoint from the WAR package, my browser tries to download the plain JSP file.

For better insight, here's a link to the project in latest state: https://github.com/comroid-git/comroid.org/tree/spring/auth

I'm afraid it's probably something terrifically stupid. But I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

As a result of further investigation, it seems to have been a dependency problem still where i was not including all necessary dependencies. It workis now partially with the following dependencies (not including spring dependencies):

```
    implementation 'javax.servlet:jstl'
    implementation 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper'
    implementation 'jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl:jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.web:jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
```

Furthermore, the issue seems to be rather related to how IntelliJ Ultimate launches applications within itself - I've always been using the Services View.

However, when first packaging the application using gradle's `bootWar` task, then running that WAR package, it works as expected now.

Using the `bootRun` Task works alright for debugging the application.